# ngrok callback URL validation failed

Tags: node.js, facebook-chatbot

I'm new to chatbot using node, i'm creating a chatbot and using ngrok for tunelling. When i try to setup webhooks on facebook messenger the callback URL validation fails.[image]

[image: check images for reference]

[image]

Comment: Did you try with http in facebook developper instead https ? If it's not this we'll need your NodeJS code to find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I was also having the same issue. It is because of ngrok inserts some special characters inside URL and also creates with http may be. So, I am using [localtunnel](https://github.com/localtunnel/localtunnel) instead of ngrok and it works with ease as well as we can create our desired subdomain with this package. The steps to install localtunnel are

```
npm install -g localtunnel
lt -s chatbot-subdomain -p PORT
```

It will create a URL https://chatbot-subdomain.localtunnel.me which you can use inside facebook developer platform.